# Custom Ribbon in Outlook VSTO goes 'missing' if not in VSTO project's root?

Tags: c#, vsto, outlook-addin, outlook-2010

I have a bare bones VSTO Outlook Add-in.  I've added an empty Ribbon via this [article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mcsuksoldev/archive/2010/10/01/building-and-deploying-an-outlook-2010-add-in-part-1-of-2.aspx) and it works.

The `Ribbon.cs` and the `Ribbon.xml` files currently reside in my project's root but if I move them to a sub folder (say `AddIn\Ribbon`) there are no compile errors but when I run Outlook the addin's ribbon is missing.  Playing around with it, it appears that the Ribbon.xml must stay in my project's root for the ribbon to appear.

I don't understand this behavior; is there a setting or something that manually references the addin's ribbon location?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out after a fresh look:  After adding a new Ribbon (XML) item, there is a generated function `GetCustomUI` that uses the path to XML file as the look-up key in the assembly's resources for the file.

So when moving a file, you should change the call to `GetResourceText` from something like this:

```
   return GetResourceText("MyAddin.Ribbon.xml");
```

to something like this:

```
   return GetResourceText("MyAddin.Ribbons.Ribbon.xml");
```

You need this because the xml file is linked as a resource in the project file which should have a line like this:

```
  <EmbeddedResource Include="Ribbons\Ribbon.xml" />
```